# storage size isn't known

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, arduino

Есть ряд параметров, которые я решил задать в виде массива, длина которого может быть разной.

Для доступа к одному из массивов параметров определил переменную, которой присваиваю адрес одного из массивов:
float * curTimeInterval[];
При компиляции получаю ошибку : storage size isn't known

Научите пожалуйста как выбрать нужный массив с параметрами и извлекать из него значения?

```
static float TimeImterval1[] PROGMEM = {0.2,0.2,0.2,2};
static int TimeImterval1N PROGMEM = 4;
static float TimeImterval2[] PROGMEM = {0.2,0.2,0.2,0.5,0.2,2};
static int TimeImterval2N PROGMEM = 6;

float * curTimeInterval[];
int curLength;

 _ticker.detach();

switch (curTickPGM)
{
  case 2:
    curTimeInterval = &TimeImterval2;
    curLength = TimeImterval2N;
    break;

  default:
    curTimeInterval = &TimeImterval1;
    curLength = TimeImterval1N;
    break;
}
```

Comment: Так а зачем у вас там `[]` после `curTimeInterval`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что скрывается за `PROGMEM` ?

А так - все просто:

```
static float TimeImterval1[] = {0.2f,0.2f,0.2f,2f};
static int TimeImterval1N = size(TimeImterval1);
static float TimeImterval2[] = {0.2f,0.2f,0.2f,0.5f,0.2f,2f};
static int TimeImterval2N = size(TimeImterval2);


float * curTimeInterval;


    case 2:
        curTimeInterval = TimeImterval2;
        curLength = TimeImterval2N;
        break;

    default:
        curTimeInterval = TimeImterval1;
        curLength = TimeImterval1N;
        break;
```

Comment: Спасибо !
PROGMEM - это опция для Arduino - что данные лежат во флеш

Answer (score 2):

Уберите скобки.

```
float * curTimeInterval;
```